# How do i deploy to Azure from BitBucket, when my project references assemblies in other BitBucket repos?

Tags: azure, deployment, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Website that is connected to BitBucket for deployment. The site knows to deploy the MyProject repo..

However, the solution file in that repo also references 2 other .csproj from a different repo (also on BitBucket) called SharedLibs. Inside the SharedLibs repo are around 10 libraries and MyProject solution file references 2 of them - the DBAccess csproj and the ExcelFileMaker csproj. The way I've cloned SharedLibs into a peer folder of MyProject, means that MyProject.csproj references "....\SharedLibs\DBAccess\DBAccess.csproj" and a similar path for ExcelFileMaker

```
+- MyProject            //on bitbucket in a repo called 'MyProject'
| +- MyProject.csproj   //references DBAccess.csproj and ExcelFileMaker.csproj
|
+- SharedLibs           //on bitbucket in a repo called 'SharedLibs'
  +- DBAccess
  | +- DBAccess.csproj
  |
  +- ExcelFileMaker
    +-ExcelFileMaker.csproj
```

Azure doesn't deploy MyProject because, naturally, after it has pulled MyProject from bitbucket, it tries to access these two nonexistant directories DBAccess, and ExcelFilemaker via their relative paths in the deploy location

This seems like the sort of situation where sub-repos would be used. My understanding is that in mercurial a sub-repo is sort of a "linked repo" such that mercurial knows every time it pulls from the MyProject repo it also has to pull the latest code from the SharedLibs repo..

..thing is I haven't been able to get sub-repos to work with Azure.. I'm not sure how to get Azure to pull the contents of N number of repos when deploying

The only way I've found to make it work so far is to take the libraries out of shared and put them directly under my project (literally copy the files, and then add them to source control of the MyProject repo, as well as there being a copy of them under source control in the SharedLibs repo). This is less than ideal, because it means that manual diffing has to be used to replicate changes to projects inside the SharedLibs repo, into the duplicate code bases for the few libs that MyProject is using

I'm certain this problem must have been solved already, because code-reuse and modularisation is top of most coders' agenda. Can someone please tell me how to make this work on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom deployment script [1] and then add a step to pull those repos down and copy the files over to the source directory before the build step occurs.

In the deployment script you will have access to some environment variables you can use in copying the files [2].

[1] http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.VBtuFvldUZw
[2] https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this eventually we switched things out completely, took all those libraries and made them into NuGet packages and hosted them on our private server. Azure will now restore them when it builds the main project, and we can update the libraries independently of the main project and build at will